# How to create multiple nested routes for Front and admin pages

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I am facing issue in routing for front section of website and admin section,
My code look like this:
App.js

```
 class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Router />
        </BrowserRouter>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

Router.js

```
const Router = () => (
  <>
    <Switch>
      <Home>
        <Route
          component={({ match }) => (
            <div>
              <Route exact path="/" component={Main} />
              <Route exact path="/read" component={Read} />
              <Route exact path="/post" component={Posts} />
              <Route exact path="/user" component={Users} />
              <Route exact path="/signup" component={Signup} />
              <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
              <Route exact path="/post/:id" component={Post} />
              <Route exact path="/forgot-password" component={ForgotPassword} />
            </div>
          )}
        />
      </Home>
      {/*Admin dashboard*/}
      <Dashboard>
        <Route
          component={({ match }) => (
            <div>
              <Route exact path="/admin" component={MainDashboard} />
              <Route exact path="/admin/post" component={PostManage} />
              <Route exact path="/admin/user" component={UserManage} />
            </div>
          )}
        />
      </Dashboard>
      <Route component={NoMatchPage} />
    </Switch>
  </>
);


export default Router;
```

Dashboard.js

```
const Dashboard = props => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Sidebar />
      {props.children}
    </div>
  );
};
export default Dashboard;
```

I want implement such that Home and Dashboard have different routing. But When i use this code, it only able to route Home nested routes i.e. /read,/post are working fine.
But /admin,/admin/post are not showing up.

Answer (score 1):

You have made all the routes "exact" which is making trouble for you.
You should make the parent to be just "path".

**For example:**

Remove the ***"exact"*** from

```
<Route path="/admin" component={MainDashboard} />
```

and your nested routes of admin will start working.